# Insert Chart In Asp.Net using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, charts

I have in my project a report that calculate some event ...i want insert a chart in this report but its unshown when i complie it ....

its shown like un appernce image :(

**RunTime**

[image]

---

**Application**

[image]

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What version of Crystal Reports are you using, and what code do you have to generate the chart?

Comment: "its shown like **un appernce** image..." what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no Solution ...!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure connectString are goods ? I means, probably some configuration files looking for localhost.

I don't know Crystal Reports, but in Reporting Services, you'll see warnings in the Application explaining stuffs like this, otherwise it should be the config.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts of mine:

- In your Crystal Reports 10, can you see the chart show up with all the data correctly (in the Preview tab)? This is **critical**: If you can't see anything in your Preview, there's no point to troubleshoot it in your viewer application.
- Your runtime screenshot seems like it is a web application (ASP.NET)? Check whether the web app has the permission to grab data from your database. And whether your connection string is correct.
- Also, make sure the app has access to the generated image URL / directory.